# How to change normal view to compatibility view in Internet Explour from programmatically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-7, internet-explorer-10

I have an asp.net application.  They some function  and themes not working in IE 10 but after change viewer mode  compatibility  it is working,  I also add below that tag and IIS setting but still doesn't change with capability view.

The IIS setting  adds Http Response headers = name : X-UA-Compatible
                                             value :IE=edge

Comment: Hi pathum just look into this post i hope it solves ur prob if not reply back......... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge

Comment: Also this below line would help ur cause i believe...................<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">

Comment: I added this still not fixed

Comment: The HTTP response header would work fine if the browser received it. Use Fiddler or the F12 Network tab to verify that the header is present.